# Failed to find configure element on wso2 call

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

We are moving our system from our development environment to production and an error has appeared on attempting to make ESB calls.

```
Failed to locate the configure element for connector
```

We have double checked that the connector is enabled and ensured that the package names match. This worked fine when run locally.

We've noticed our production environment is an older version than we were developing on. Is there a chance from 4.8.1 to 5.0.0 that could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of the connectors are 4.9 and later so that could most definitely cause it. They are also built on different Carbon versions wich only increases incompatibility.

You really want to make sure that dev and test environments are similar to production. Both in ESB versions as well as Java versions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, that would have been the ideal answer, but we were never able to get a 4.8.1 server running in dev and we decided to just hope it wouldn't make a difference. Turns out it did! I think the plan now is to abandon the connectors and implement the java logic in class mediators. This isn't going to be a happy transition, I think. Thanks, though! :-)